# Using dplyr "Filter" with a Vector of Zip Codes

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make a vector of zip codes to be used as in dplyr for filtering a dataset. The dataset has multiple variables, but for my question I just showed the zip_code Variable.

```
head(df)
     df
1 75251
2 75219
3 76051
4 75209
5 75224
6 76006

school_zips_V <- c(
"75244",
"75211",
"75134",
"75038",
"75150",
"75243")
```

I tried using Str_Detect from code i've researched online but get errors.

```
Clean_Data <- filter(df, str_detect(school_zips_V, paste(school_zips_V)))
```

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 4429, not 21

Comment: And make sure your `zip_code` column in your `df` is of the same type as your `school_zips_V`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `%in%`, no need for `str_detect`:

```
df %>%
  filter(zip_code %in% school_zips_V)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `%in%`:

```r
library(dplyr)
school_zips_V <- c(
  "75244",
  "75211",
  "75134",
  "75038",
  "75150",
  "75243")
df <- tibble(zip = c("75251", "75244", "90210"))
filter(df, zip %in% school_zips_V)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   zip  
#>   <chr>
#> 1 75244
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>